# Security level access nodejs and passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, ejs, passport-local

I am currently making a Timecard system for employees to use at the job I work at (just to make things a little less chaotic) and I would like to have regular users and managers. My basic structure that I want to achieve is this for the Schemas:

`User
  ---name
  ---password
  ---isClockedIn
  ---phoneNumber
  ---isManager
    --if isManager == true
    --deleteUser
    --addUser
    --etc`

Now, the current User schema I have is this:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    first_name: String,
    middle_initial: String,
    last_name: String,
    phone: Number,
    isManager: Boolean,
    isLoggedIn: Boolean,
    points_accrued: Number
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

I am not sure if I should add an extra schema for the Admin permissions or really how to go about giving a regular user that type of access.

Now for my routes, I want the user (Employee) and the Admin to see pretty much the same view, except the manager will have some additional links that will allow his to see all users, delete them, change timecards ect.

for now this is what my routes look like:

```
//INDEX SHOW USER INFO
router.get("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, middleware.isManager, function(req, res){
    User.find({}, function(err, currentUser){
        if(err){
            console.log("error occured");
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("users/index", {user: currentUser});
        }
    });
});
```

And then my middleware is going to look like this:

```
middlewareObj.isManager = function(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated() && req.isManager === true){
        //Load Page for admins view example: see all employees clocked in and admins timesheet
        return next();
    } else {
        //Load Page to only show current Users timesheet
        return next();  
}
```

now this begs the question, would it be better and more fluid for the first page to be the same for both user and admin (like show generic time info for that particular employee) and the if the user is an admin have a link show up that only they can access to make any low level changes, OR have the admin see all of that data on his homepage without clicking on a different link?
And further more, how can I make my middleware tell the route, and then the route tell the html (ejs in my case) what to show and what not to display.

I appreciate it and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For the first ask i think is only a business logic, so depend of you what you want. For experience i prefer the first way in case of small projects becouse is more fast to implement (show/hide element of same page), for complex projects can be usefull do *also* a different page only for the admin.

For the second ask, you can simply put a condition, assume, like your example, you pass the user to ejs.

```
<% if (user && user.isManage) { %>
  <button>Admin button</button>
<% } %>
```